# How to upload a file into AWS lambda with a REST API call from Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to upload a file into AWS Lambda using Postman but not from aws cli or console and without creating an API. Just like how you can post a record into Dynamo DB from postman with only the Access key and Secret Access key by hitting a standard URL (https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/) , can I do the same in AWS Lambda by just making a REST API call?

Comment: why the unaccept? If you need more help feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes- but you'll have to take a bit more responsibility for the process.

Just like dynamo, you can invoke a lambda function from the console or by using lambda invoke from the aws cli (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html)

Lambda *has* to have a JSON payload (that becomes your `event` argument in the handler). But there's no other requirements beyond that if you're invoking directly.

If you want to send a file, all you need to do, therefore, is find a way to encode it in JSON. A common approach would be to base64 encode it.

To invoke a lambda from Postman:

**Method**: `POST`

**Request URL**: `https://lambda.$REGION.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/$FUNCTION_NAME/invocations`

**Headers**:

- X-Amz-Invocation-Type: `RequestResponse`
- X-Amz-Client-Context: `e30=` *(this is just an empty closure (`{}`) in base64)*

**Body**:

```
{
  filedata: 'base64encodedfile-made-using-link-below'
}
```

To get the value of `filedata` you'll need to use a conversion tool like this one (https://www.base64encode.org/) to get the base64 version of your file.

**Authentication**: AWS Signature

(You can read the service guide for more information on this call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

Your lambda will then need to decode the base64 encoding to get the binary file. For example:

**lambda.js**

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {   
    const { filedata } = event;
    const data = Buffer.from(filedata, 'base64').toString(); // or whatever format you need to read.
    callback(null, "some success message");
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't ask the exact question. I don't want to use cli nor console. Is there any other way?

Comment: OK- I've made the answer a bit more Postman specific- although because lambda takes JSON (not binary), you'll _always_ have to encode the file as base64.

Comment: Thanks, but I am struck at Create Function method. I am unable to find s3 key of s3 bucket. Can you explain how to find them and send the http request.

Comment: If you want to do that then, you'll need to also send the name of the key/bucket in that json body (e.g. `{ filedata: 'base64encodedfile-made-using-link-below', bucket: 'bucket-name', key: 'key-name' }`) You can then use that in the `S3.putObject` function. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property)